# npm start throwing error when trying to create a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to web development using react. So, i did the following -
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

But, it is throwing a error which are as follows:

```
E:\Study\React-course\React-app\my-app>npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start E:\Study\React-course\React-app\my-app
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.5/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from E:\Study\React-course\React-app\my-app\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-20T07_10_52_845Z-debug.log

E:\Study\React-course\React-app\my-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using  this (npm install -g create-react-app create-react-app) try creating react app using ( npx create-react-app my-app)
And for more clarification follow this
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Is node js installed on your system if yes then what version is it??

Comment: I have nodejs v14.5.0 installed

Comment: I would suggest you to use LTS(long term support) version -of node js not current version of node js as it might be unstable and might be creating issues.

Comment: And also do make sure that you have not changed your installation folder while installing node js and also do check the path variable that is this (C:\Windows\System32) added in your path variable or not. Check this thread https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6950

Comment: I have installed stable version of node and added path variable but still no luck

Comment: I guess the only thing left is restarting the system 

Comment: still nothing. Is there any alternative way by which i can do it? I have a deadline within a week :(

Comment: There is one way you can write react code online and practice it there in https://codesandbox.io/embed/new?codemirror=1 this provides you all your project setup

Comment: Or try once more uninstall everything which you installed for the setup and give it a new start try cleaning cache and remove the npm cache too remove everything related to node and see if it works than hope it works.

Comment: I solved the issue. The  default scripts version is 3.4.1 and it was causing the problem. I installed 2.1.8 and int worked fine. Thanks you alot.

Comment: Finally, it worked great  don't forget to hit the tick on answer hope it might help someone else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218206/discussion-between-gagangaur-and-anita-shrivastava).

Answer (score 0):

Please do not write a special character on your local system folder

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).